# Passing parameter fail by CreateThread?

Tags: windows, multithreading, createthread

My Code like this

`starts` is a array of `DWORD32`

`threads` is a array of `HANDLE`

```
void initThreads(HANDLE* threads, int size)
{
    DWORD32* starts = (DWORD32*)malloc(sizeof(DWORD32) * size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        starts[i] = num_steps / numThreads * i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)  
    {
        DWORD32* para = starts + i;
        printf("create %ld\n", *para);
        threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, portionCal, (void*)para, 0, NULL);
    }
    free(starts);
}

DWORD WINAPI portionCal(LPVOID pArg) 
{ 
   double x, portionSum = 0.0;
   DWORD32 start = *(DWORD32*)pArg;
   printf("start at %d\n", start);
}
```

But the result is

```
create 0
create 25000000
start at 0
create 50000000
create 75000000
start at 50000000
start at -17891602
start at 25000000
```

Why the result look like this?

Comment: I rolled back your question edit. You asked the question. And you had two answers to the question. There's simply no point in repeating the answer in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't see the scope of *starts* but this can be guessed at from the failure.  It is probably a local variable, long gone when the thread starts running.  So you'll just read garbage.  You'll need a stable pointer, get one from a global variable or malloc().

After edit: don't call free() like that.  It has to remain stable until *all* threads have completed using it.  You could consider reference counting it with InterlockedDecrement().

Comment: starts is no local value, and I put the full code in the question

Answer (score 1):

You free the `starts` array immediately after creating the threads. So what happens is that the threads are passed pointers to memory that may have been freed before the threads have a chance to read it. If that happens, the resulting behaviour is undefined.

You can resolve the problem by ensuring that the memory referred to by the pointers has a lifetime that extends beyond that of the threads. Typically you do that by allocating off the heap the data for each thread, and letting the thread call `free` when it has taken a copy of the information.

In this case, the easier way to resolve the problem is to pass the integer value rather than a pointer to it. Like this:

```
threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, portionCal, (void*)starts[i], 0, NULL);
```

And in your thread:

```
DWORD32 start = (DWORD32)pArg;
```

Comment: thanks I find the error, I free the starts immediately before the thread init